# MySQL order by count subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, subquery

I have an "Author" table, containing Authors(Nicknames & IDs).

In the Content table, each item has a field "Author" containing the ID of the author who made it.

I want to select all authors using a SELECT query, and to **order them by them amount of Content they created**.

This is what I tried so far :

```
SELECT id,Nickname FROM Authors 
WHERE 1 ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Content WHERE Author=id) ASC
```

It runs, but the output is invalid - it has no specific order...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT a.id, a.Nickname
FROM Authors a
WHERE 1
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Content c WHERE c.Author = a.id) ASC;
```

This makes the correlation explicit.  Your version would produce unsorted results if `Content` had an `id` column -- which is likely.

More commonly, you would want the count in the `SELECT`, and you would do:

```
SELECT a.id, a.Nickname, COUNT(c.Author) as num_content
FROM Authors a LEFT JOIN
     Content c
     ON c.Author = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.Nickname
ORDER BY num_content ASC;
```

Comment: I tried it out, and your answer(the 1st query) works like a charm. Also, it's very logical and well explained. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT a.id,a.Nickname
FROM Authors  a
LEFT JOIN Content c
  ON c.Author=a.id
GROUP BY a.id,a.Nickname
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```